# How can I user postgresql native password to login database?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I deployed a aurora cluster for postgresql engine and enabled IAM authentication (Password and IAM database authentication). I created a user with below commands:

```
CREATE USER test  WITH PASSWORD '123456';
GRANT rds_iam TO test;
```

I am able to login the database with `aws rds generate-db-auth-token` auto generated token but I can't login with the native password.

The command I am using to login is:

`psql "host=dev-ams-engine-aurora-auroracluster.cluster-xxxxx.ap-southeast-2.rds.amazonaws.com dbname=Test user=test"`

The error I got when login with native password is:

`psql: error: could not connect to server: FATAL:  PAM authentication failed for user "test"`

Based on AWS doc:

```
Password and IAM database authentication

Manage your database user credentials through your DB engine's native password authentication 
features and IAM users and roles. IAM helps an administrator securely control access to AWS 
resources. IAM administrators control who can be authenticated and authorized for RDS resources.
```

It seems that it should support both IAM user/role and native password. Why can't I use native password to login?

Comment: I would not expect the same role to support both at the same time. A specific role either has `rds_iam`, or does not.

Comment: Does `ids_iam` role stop login via username/password? Where should I look at the detail about rds_iam role?